# 'menu-trigger' script not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with my code when using IE 11. The trigger button won't respond when I try to click it but in Chrome, Firefox and MS Edge it's working fine.

Please help me with this. I've been searching a lot but still, I haven't solved this.

```
$(function() {
  $(".menu-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".g-nav").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/venJ7/pen/KKKaxKO

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at what @Deepak-MSFT said below, if your code isn't executing then take a look in the console and see what errors are popping up and report back. or provide more code for us to look at. There is nothing wrong with what is above.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to test your code with IE 11 browser and found that it is working without any issue.

Tested code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.Nav {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.menu-trigger i {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 44px;
  height: 7px;
  top: 24px;
  right: 23px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu-trigger,
.menu-trigger i {
  position: absolute;
}

.menu-trigger i:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 12px;
}

.menu-trigger i:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-trigger i:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.menu-trigger.active i:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-trigger.active i:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-trigger.active i:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 24px;
}

.g-nav {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
  $(".menu-trigger").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".g-nav").fadeToggle();
  });
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Nav">
  <a class="menu-trigger">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </a>
  <nav class="g-nav" id="g-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p><a href="#">MENU</a></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

I suggest you to run this sample in IE 11 to check whether it is working or not.

If issue persist than try to check the console to see whether there is any error or warning message.

Comment: In online is working fine but when I use my local file it's not. I check the console and I don't any error or warning message.

Comment: Not sure, how your local file looks like and whether it has any other code in it. You can see in my test that I am also running the local file which is stored on drive D:\ and it is working fine. does that same local file works in other browsers? Is there any difference in code in your local file? If yes than please inform us about that. It can help to find the issue.

Comment: It's the same code I am using in my local file and it works perfectly in other browsers. I tried using my other PC also and it has the same problem with my other one. I only remove the CSS design.

Comment: Please check whether JavaScript is enabled on internet Explorer browser or not. If it disabled than your code will not work and it will not generate any error. Trying to enabled the script may help to fix the issue.

Comment: Is internet is connected on that machine when you try to run the above code locally? because you are referencing the script file which needs to download.